# Combining 2 Result sets in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, itext, resultset

I am producing a PDF file from IText from two resultset

rs1 = returns 3 rows
rs2 = returns 5 rows

So my structure goes like this:

```
while(rs1.next()){
....
}

while(rs2.next){
....
}

generatePDF(){
....
}
```

It is working well if one person requests a PDF. But if there will be two people requesting, I am generating the last person requesting.

How should I go about this?

Sorry for the grammar.

Tried in SQL Part,

First query returns 3 rows
Second query returns 5 rows.
Each unique from other row.

So when I try to union them or group. They just do cartesian joining. I am getting 15 rows all in all

Comment: please post sql query .

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154531/combine-two-sql-with-different-rows-count?noredirect=1#comment28333231_19154531

Comment: Have you seen it @John

Comment: yes but i dont understand. do you wanted to join these tables or union.union just merge result sets. but join with expend your result set by arity (no of columns ) point of view

Comment: then use this  select t1.PARTNER,INSOBJECT,CONTRACT from TABLE_1 as t1 ,TABLE 2 as t2 where t1.PARTNER = t2.PARTNER;

Answer (score 0):

you should use to merge 2 query 's result sets but queries should be union compatible

```
select A, B
```

`from C`
    `union`
`select A, B from D`

then you should call `generatePDF()` with in your while block.

for join

```
select t1.PARTNER,INSOBJECT,CONTRACT from TABLE_1 as t1 ,TABLE 2 as t2 where t1.PARTNER = t2.PARTNER;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do that in sql part.